# How do I use mod_pagespeed to rewrite HTML to serve images off my CDN?

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed

I simply want to rewrite pages that contain this:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/foo/bar/hello.jpg" />
```

To be this:

```
<img src="http://cdn.example.com/foo/bar/hello.jpg" />
```

I feel like this should be fairly simple, but I've spent three hours reading the docs and trying to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure you enable [domain rewriting](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/filter-domain-rewrite)
2. Then configure your [rewrite configuration to use your CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/domains#mapping_rewrite)

That ought to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks!  I was missing the domain rewriting part of the equation.